# Python Serial Read all Output (cant break out of while loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I have this code which im using to connect to a printer and send it commands. It works perfectly until it gets to the while loop, it just cant get out of it. The output prints the first few lines expected in serial than just waits until while loop goes false. how do i get out of the loop?

```
import serial
import os
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)  # open serial port
print("Device Name: " + ser.name)
while True:
    response = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    print(response)

time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a `while True:` loop is that there is no stop condition. This means that it will keep going until you manually stop your program.

What you can do is add a break statement when you don't read anything anymore.
And don't forget to use a timeout on your serial so it doesn't hang forever waiting for new data:

```
import serial
import os
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=10)  # open serial port
print("Device Name: " + ser.name)
counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    response = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    print(response)
    if response == "":
        break

time.sleep(1)
```

With this, it will read everything available then wait 10 seconds for additional data.
If there is no more data, it will return an empty string (no bytes read) and break from the loop.

Comment: is there any way to bypass the time or make it shorter? it takes ages for it to print output to terminal

Comment: @zenozlaptop I defined the timeout when creating the serial with `timeout = 10`

Of course if you want it shorter (if you're only interested in what's immediately available) you can even reduce it to zero. in which case it will only print what's currently on the serial, without waiting for any new data

Comment: Of course, it should print at least the first few lines immediately and only take a while to exit, not to print